# Do modern browsers still limit parallel downloads?

Tags: performance, http, browser

In [this Yahoo article](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/04/11/performance-research-part-4/) from 2007, the authors argue that static assets should be split across different hostnames because browsers follow a suggestion from the HTTP/1.1 spec to limit parallel downloads to two per hostname.

My question is, do modern browsers still follow this limit? Using firebug, I noticed that my browser is downloading many more than 2 files in parallel.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Microsoft till IE 7 is limited to two IE 8 and 9 to six. Firefox is limited to six. There is a fix out from ms to modify all to ten: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282402

you can asume that all modern browsers have a default limit of six

**Update**

Here's a **[good source](http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network)** for comparing actual browser and their `MaxConnextions`

Comment: Links seems not to be working, trying to get some uptodate info (altough not official) found this 2020 post: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/why-does-your-browser-limit-number-concurrent-ishwar-rimal/ (HTTP1 vs HTTP2 max number of connections)and this older link http://sgdev-blog.blogspot.com/2014/01/maximum-concurrent-connection-to-same.html

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is still a limit. With Firefox, you can go to `about:config` and look at the value of `network.http.max-connections` and `network.http.max-connections-per-server`.